# How to link all associated products into configurable product while uploading

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, import-from-excel

Some of my products are configurable products with different sizes. Now I want to upload all these from import system of magento. Problem is when I am importing configurable products and its associated product, all product are uploaded but associated products are not link with their configurable product.

Can somebody sort out this problem or is there any way to import configurable products with its associated products.

Thanks

Comment: did you have a associated_products column in you CSV?

Comment: Yes I have field in CSV.

Comment: you can watch this video will help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtUUM7oDZKg